# LaTeX3: selective expansion

Tags: expansion, latex3

I have narrowed my problem to the next oversimplified token list (there are much more tokens that I do not know in advance)

```
\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { \myFoo \myBar { \myBaz } }
```

where for example

```
\cs_set:Npn \myFoo { Foo }
\cs_set:Npn \myBar { Bar }
\cs_set:Npn \myBaz { Baz }
```

I want to expand only `\myBar` and `\myBaz` and leave \myFoo unexpanded to turn `\l_tmpa_tl` into

```
\myFoo Bar { Baz }
```

To expand only `\myBar`, I can use a variant of `\tl_replace_once:Nnn`. Here is my code snippet

```
\tl_set:Nx \l_tmpb_tl { \myBar }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_replace_once:Nnn { NnV }
\tl_replace_once:NnV \l_tmpa_tl { \myBar } \l_tmpb_tl
```

the result is actually

```
\myFoo Bar { \myBaz }
```

But how can I expand `\myBaz` while it is inside a group ?

Some kind of deep replace would help, or at least a mean to create the token list `{ Baz }` from only `\myBaz`.

Comment: Sorry but it is quite unclear what you mean "by the rest unexpanded". There is nothing else in your snippets, and a  simple `\tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \myBar { \myBaz } }` would give `\l_tmpa_tl=Bar{Baz}.`

Comment: @Ulrike As I told, this is an oversimplified example. Your command does not make selective extension, it expands everything. I'll add one more macro to be more precise.

Comment: You can still use the `x` variant and place `\exp_not:N` in front of the variable that you want to leave as is.

Comment: @cgnieder Wouldn't that mean looping over the tl contents and insert a `\exp_not:N` just before any macro but `\myBar` and `\myBaz`? I barely see how to do that, some recursion could be involded.

Comment: Maybe you oversimplified your example. There is no need for looping in the example of your question

Comment: @cgnieder You certainly missed the "there are much more tokens that I do not know in advance" part that I have added since Ulrike's comment

Comment: And these “much more tokens“: you want them expanded? Or not? Or some expanded and some not (by which pattern)? Do you know (and can you influence) how the tokenlist `\l_tmpa_tl` is built?

Comment: All the other tokens must be left unexpanded. Only 2 macros must be expanded, one at the top level `\myBar` and one inside braces `\myBaz`.

Comment: @JérômeLAURENS and do you know anything about the position of the macros you want to expand in the token list? Is it always `\a \b { \c } \d \e \f ...` where you want to expand only `\b` and `\c`? What kind of expansion do you want? `o`, `f` or `e`/`x`?

Comment: I can safely group what is before \b into one big token such that the group containing \c is always 3rd in the list. Actually my \b and \c both need x expansion

Answer (score 1):

Given your final comment that you can group the initial unexpanded tokens, it seems you only need consider three terms. This shows a log of

```
> \l_tmpa_tl=macro:
->{\myFoo \myFoo \myFoo }\myBar {\myBaz }.
l.11 \show\l_tmpa_tl
                    
? 
> \l_tmpb_tl=\long macro:
->{\myFoo \myFoo \myFoo }Bar{Baz}.
l.20 \show\l_tmpb_tl
```

If you don't want the first tokens grouped in the final output you can use

`\cs_set:Npn\zz_aux:NNn#1#2#3{\exp_not:n{#1}#2{#3}}`

But the output above is generated with

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set:Npn \myFoo { Foo }
\cs_set:Npn \myBar { Bar }
\cs_set:Npn \myBaz { Baz }

\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { {\myFoo\myFoo\myFoo} \myBar { \myBaz } }

\show\l_tmpa_tl

\cs_set:Npn\zz_aux:NNn#1#2#3{{\exp_not:n{#1}}#2{#3}}
\cs_set:Npn\zz_expand:NN#1#2{
   \cs_set:Npx#2{\exp_after:wN\zz_aux:NNn#1}
}

\zz_expand:NN \l_tmpa_tl \l_tmpb_tl

\show\l_tmpb_tl
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```